# Replace period with dash via command line?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

Here's my current command:

```
sed 's/\./-/' file.txt > CLEANED.txt
```

What I'm trying to do is replace all periods in my file with a dash.  Some lines have multiple periods and I need all of them replaced with a dash - but the command above seems to just replace the first one in each line.

What am I doing wrong for it to not replace all of the periods?

Answer (score 3):

In perl, just add the `/g` [modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to your regex:

```
perl -pe 's/\./-/g' file.txt > CLEANED.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/\./-/g`: Replace all periods with dashes.  Could also use the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html): `y/./-/`

Answer (score 2):

Add `/g` for a global replacement, else it only affects the first occurrence.
Like so:

```
sed 's/\./-/g' file.txt > CLEANED.txt
```